# Null float array in java

Tags: java

I've tried to create a float array with nulls and NaNs:

`float[] fArray = {null, null};`

or

`float[] fArray = {float.NaN, float.NaN};`

Is it possible in java to do something like this?

Comment: `Float[] fArray = {null, null};`

or

    `float[] fArray = {Float.NaN, Float.NaN};`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`float` is a primitive type and can not be `null`. There is a wrapper class [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) (note the capital) that can be `null`. Also [NaN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN) is a member of `Float` not of `float`. Have a look at the [documentation of Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html).

Comment: Ah! This is where C# alias's disguised as keywords come in handy. `float.NaN == System.Single.NaN` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 float[] array = new float[]{null,null};
```

Cannot compile, float is a primitive type thus can not be null

```
  Float[] array = new Float[]{null,null};
```

Compile, Float is an object, thus can be null.